# C# SQL stored procedure (which inserts) - pass parameters and retrieve parameter

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a stored procedure on my server that inserts some parameters and returns the `ID` that was inserted. I am writing a form to do this easily but I cannot seem to get the parameter which is passed back.

To save you doing a whole bunch of possibly pointless reading, it's probably better to just pay attention to my C# code and let me know what I need to do in order to pass parameters and get one in return.

**C# Default.aspx**

```
connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionInfo"]);
sql = "aStoredProc";

command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

command.Parameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = sFirstname;
command.Parameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@SurName", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = sSurname;

connection.Open(); 
int ID = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

**SQL aStoredProc**

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM aTable WHERE ID = @ID)
  -- User exists, update details
  BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN
      UPDATE aTable
        SET 
          FirstName = @FirstName,
          SurName = @SurName,
          LastUpdate = GetDate()
        WHERE ID = @ID

        IF (@@Error != 0)
          ROLLBACK TRAN
        ELSE
          COMMIT TRAN
        END
ELSE
  -- New user
  BEGIN
    BEGIN TRAN
      INSERT aTable (
        FirstName,
        SurName,
        GetDate()
      )
        VALUES (
          @FirstName, 
          @SurName,
          @LastUpdate
      ) 

      SELECT @ID = @@IDENTITY

      IF (@@Error != 0)
        ROLLBACK TRAN
      ELSE
        COMMIT TRAN
      END
```

The parameter `@ID` is listed in the stored proc as:

```
@ID (int, Input/Output, No default)
```

and proc has 'Return integer'. This used to work fine with a VBA solution prior to a SQL Server 2005 upgrade.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633821/scope-identity-always-returning-0/8633835#8633835 for a similar question/answer.

Comment: you have a logic flaw in stored proc. (in the else 'new user' branch): any statement executing before inspecting @@ERROR will reset @@ERROR

Comment: I would also recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: Another hint: when you define `SqlParameter` with a datatype of `varchar` - **always** define a length! Otherwise, you end up with parameters of 1 character length!! So use this: `new SqlParameter("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100))` (or replace 100 with whichever value you want/need...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionInfo"]); 
sql = "aStoredProc"; 
command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection); 
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
command.Parameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = sFirstname; 
command.Parameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@SurName", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = sSurname; 
command.Parameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@SurName", SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = sSurname; 
SqlParameter ParamId = cmd.Parameters.Add( "@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
ParamId.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
command.Parameter.Add(ParamId);
connection.Open();  
command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
int ID = ParamId.Value;
connection.Close();
```

1. you have to add output paramter in Parameter collection.
2. Read Value like above.

Comment: Thanks mate will try this tomorrow.

Comment: I think 'vendor' should be 'ParamId'. But this errors at the line 'int ID = ParamId.Value;' - cannot convert object to int.

Comment: Yes I tried parsing/typecasting but to no avail. I'll keep fiddling, thanks for your help mate

Comment: `command` is an object of class `SqlCommand`, and `SqlCommand` class doesn't have a property with the name: `Direction`. In `command.Direction` the object must be of `SqlParameter` class. Isn't that right?

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your SQL, it should look like this:

```
 INSERT aTable (FirstName,SurName,LastUpdate)
    VALUES (@FirstName, @SurName, GetDate() )
```

Not like this:

```
 INSERT aTable (
    FirstName,
    SurName,
    GetDate()
  )
    VALUES (
      @FirstName, 
      @SurName,
      @LastUpdate
  )
```

Comment: Yeah it's not my exact SQL, just a rough idea of what it is.